# Insert a character at a specific location in a string

Tags: string, r

I would like to insert an extra character (or a new string) at a specific location in a string. For example, I want to insert `d` at the fourth location in `abcefg` to get `abcdefg`.

Now I am using:

```
old <- "abcefg"
n <- 4
paste(substr(old, 1, n-1), "d", substr(old, n, nchar(old)), sep = "")
```

I could write a one-line simple function for this task, but I am just curious if there is an existing function for that.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can do this with regular expressions and `gsub`.

```
gsub('^([a-z]{3})([a-z]+)$', '\\1d\\2', old)
# [1] "abcdefg"
```

If you want to do this dynamically, you can create the expressions using `paste`:

```
letter <- 'd'
lhs <- paste0('^([a-z]{', n-1, '})([a-z]+)$')
rhs <- paste0('\\1', letter, '\\2')
gsub(lhs, rhs, old)
# [1] "abcdefg"
```

---

as per DWin's comment,you may want this to be more general.

```
gsub('^(.{3})(.*)$', '\\1d\\2', old)
```

This way any three characters will match rather than only lower case.  DWin also suggests using `sub` instead of `gsub`.  This way you don't have to worry about the `^` as much since `sub` will only match the first instance.  But I like to be explicit in regular expressions and only move to more general ones as I understand them and find a need for more generality.

---

as Greg Snow noted, you can use another form of regular expression that looks behind matches:

```
sub( '(?<=.{3})', 'd', old, perl=TRUE )
```

and could also build my dynamic `gsub` above using `sprintf` rather than `paste0`:

```
lhs <- sprintf('^([a-z]{%d})([a-z]+)$', n-1)
```

or for his `sub` regular expression:

```
lhs <- sprintf('(?<=.{%d})',n-1)
```

Comment: I liked the regex solution but would use `sub()` and I would suggest a more general pattern: `^(.{3})(.*$)"`. at the moment any non-lowercase letter will sabotage the replacement.

Comment: I like to be as specific as I can with regular expressions so they fail rather than succeed unexpectedly.  But you make a good point!

Comment: @Justin Thank you for pointing out the `gsub` function. I know these pattern matching functions are really powerful but don't actually know how to use them. They seem to be very complicated. I need to google more stuff on them.

Comment: You can use look behind matches to get the correct position without capturing: `sub( '(?<=.{3})', 'd', old, perl=TRUE )` or `gsub( '(?<=^.{3})', 'd', old, perl=TRUE )`.  Which is simpler is probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Also, I think this on one of the cases where `sprintf` may be simpler than `paste0` in the dynamic case: `lhs <- sprintf('^([a-z]{%d})([a-z]+)$', n-1)` or `lhs <- sprintf('(?<=.{%d})',n-1)`.

Comment: @GregSnow I often forget about `perl=TRUE` and loose out on a lot of those handy features of regexes! And you're probably right regarding `sprintf` too.  I've added those for posterity.

Comment: For more than 255 characters you need `perl = TRUE`.  Otherwise, you get this: `Error in gsub("^(.{256})(.*)$", "\\1\\2", test_list[[1]]) : 
  invalid regular expression '^(.{256})(.*)$', reason 'Invalid contents of {}'`

Answer (score 55):

`stringi` package for the rescue once again! The most simple and elegant solution among presented ones.

`stri_sub` function allows you to extract parts of the string and substitute parts of it like this:

```
x <- "abcde"
stri_sub(x, 1, 3) # from first to third character
# [1] "abc"
stri_sub(x, 1, 3) <- 1 # substitute from first to third character
x
# [1] "1de"
```

But if you do this:

```
x <- "abcde"
stri_sub(x, 3, 2) # from 3 to 2 so... zero ?
# [1] ""
stri_sub(x, 3, 2) <- 1 # substitute from 3 to 2 ... hmm
x
# [1] "ab1cde"
```

then no characters are removed but new one are inserted. Isn't that cool? :)

Comment: Would you know how to insert at multiple locations with this elegant method?

Comment: Here I naively tried to use `reduce()` but it looks clumsy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336114

Comment: Excellent approach to a problem that has troubled me for some time

Comment: Interesting function but the `stri_sub <-` isn't easily put into pipe while the `sub` function is.  (that's important only if you want to pipe...)

Comment: Good point @Bastien - you can create an issue, maybe we should add another function - `stri_sub_pipe` to solve this? 
https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/

Comment: @Bastien & @ bartektartanus you are probably aware of this: it's pipeable by now via``stringi::stri_sub_replace(x, 3,2, value = 1)``

Answer (score 8):

@Justin's answer is the way I'd actually approach this because of its flexibility, but [this](http://onertipaday.blogspot.in/2007/06/string-manipulation-insert-delim.html) could also be a fun approach.

You can treat the string as "fixed width format" and specify where you want to insert your character:

```
paste(read.fwf(textConnection(old), 
               c(4, nchar(old)), as.is = TRUE), 
      collapse = "d")
```

Particularly nice is the output when using `sapply`, since you get to see the original string as the "name".

```
newold <- c("some", "random", "words", "strung", "together")
sapply(newold, function(x) paste(read.fwf(textConnection(x), 
                                          c(4, nchar(x)), as.is = TRUE), 
                                 collapse = "-WEE-"))
#            some          random           words          strung        together 
#   "some-WEE-NA"   "rand-WEE-om"    "word-WEE-s"   "stru-WEE-ng" "toge-WEE-ther"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your original way of doing this (i.e. splitting the string at an index and pasting in the inserted text) could be made into a generic function like so:

```
split_str_by_index <- function(target, index) {
  index <- sort(index)
  substr(rep(target, length(index) + 1),
         start = c(1, index),
         stop = c(index -1, nchar(target)))
}

#Taken from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/101023.html
interleave <- function(v1,v2)
{
  ord1 <- 2*(1:length(v1))-1
  ord2 <- 2*(1:length(v2))
  c(v1,v2)[order(c(ord1,ord2))]
}

insert_str <- function(target, insert, index) {
  insert <- insert[order(index)]
  index <- sort(index)
  paste(interleave(split_str_by_index(target, index), insert), collapse="")
}
```

Example usage:

```
> insert_str("1234567890", c("a", "b", "c"), c(5, 9, 3))
[1] "12c34a5678b90"
```

This allows you to insert a vector of characters at the locations given by a vector of indexes. The `split_str_by_index` and `interleave` functions are also useful on their own.

**Edit:**

I revised the code to allow for indexes in any order. Before, indexes needed to be in ascending order.

Answer (score 3):

It took me some time to understand the regular expression, afterwards I found my way with the numbers I had

The end result was

```
old <- "89580000"
gsub('^([0-9]{5})([0-9]+)$', '\\1-\\2', old)
```

Answer (score 3):

similar to yours!

First make sure to load tidyverse package, and then use both paste0 and gsub.

Here is the exact code:

```
paste0(substr(old, 1,3), "d", substr(old,4,6))
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made a custom function called `substr1` to deal with extracting, replacing and inserting chars in a string. Run these codes at the start of every session. Feel free to try it out and let me know if it needs to be improved.

```
# extraction
substr1 <- function(x,y) {
  z <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(x),''),function(w) paste(na.omit(w[y]),collapse=''))
  dim(z) <- dim(x)
  return(z) }

# substitution + insertion
`substr1<-` <- function(x,y,value) {
  names(y) <- c(value,rep('',length(y)-length(value)))
  z <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(x),''),function(w) {
    v <- seq(w)
    names(v) <- w
    paste(names(sort(c(y,v[setdiff(v,y)]))),collapse='') })
  dim(z) <- dim(x)
  return(z) }

# demonstration
abc <- 'abc'
substr1(abc,1)
# "a"
substr1(abc,c(1,3))
# "ac"
substr1(abc,-1)
# "bc"
substr1(abc,1) <- 'A'
# "Abc"
substr1(abc,1.5) <- 'A'
# "aAbc"
substr1(abc,c(0.5,2,3)) <- c('A','B')
# "AaB"
```

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can use `regmatches` to *insert a character at a specific location in a string*.

```
old <- "abcefg"
n <- 4
regmatches(old, `attr<-`(n, "match.length", 0)) <- "d"

old
#[1] "abcdefg"
```

This could also be used with a regex to find the location to insert.

```
s <- "abcefg"
regmatches(s, regexpr("(?<=c)", s, perl=TRUE)) <- "d"

s
#[1] "abcdefg"
```

And works also for multiple matches with individual repacements at different matches.

```
s <- "abcefg abcefg"
regmatches(s, gregexpr("(?<=c)", s, perl=TRUE)) <- list(1:2)

s
#[1] "abc1efg abc2efg"
```