# r - Inser a charcter at a specific location in a stringsEND

Tags: regex, string, r

I'm curious: is it possible to insert a character to the specific place to END of string with regular expressions.

I found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863599/insert-a-character-at-a-specific-location-in-a-string) very helpful.

But i did not found a way how to insert character to the second last place.

```
old <- "1234"
```

I will have:

```
new <- "12:34"
```

I did it with:

```
sub( '(?<=.{2})', ':', old, perl=TRUE )
```

but this is second (from the beginning, not from the end).

Comment: Is the title intended to be like this?

Comment: Hello @rpax, and what is wrong with the title of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know r syntax, but have a try with:

```
sub( '(..)$', ':\\1', old, perl=TRUE )
```

Comment: personaly I prefer this one :) (+1)

Comment: Thanks @M42, 
regex is clear to me now. 
Can you please explain what ':\\1' or '\\1:\\2' mean?

Comment: @AndriusZ: `\\1` means the content of the first capture group, ie. the last two character of the string in this case. Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a look *behind*, use a look *ahead*:

```
sub( '(?=..$)', ':', old, perl=TRUE )
```

The `$` anchor matches the end of the string.