# Make 10 from the numbers 1,1,5 and 8 using the 4 operations, by brute force

Tags: r, brute-force

I tried to calculate the following problem by brute force using R (under the assumption that a single pair of parenthesis would suffice).

> Make 10 from the numbers 1, 1, 5, 8. You can use the operations + – *
>   / ().  You have to use all the numbers, and use each number exactly
>   once. The operations can be repeated (like 1 + 1 + 5 + 8) and you
>   don’t have to use each operation.

I did the following and got the correct answer, but I would like your ideas for better ways of addressing that problem.

```
## Helper functions for inserting characters into strings
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863599/insert-a-character-at-a-specific-location-in-a-string/25416334#25416334

  split_str_by_index <- function(target, index) {
    index <- sort(index)
    substr(rep(target, length(index) + 1),
           start = c(1, index),
           stop = c(index -1, nchar(target)))
  }

  #Taken from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/101023.html
  interleave <- function(v1,v2)
  {
    ord1 <- 2*(1:length(v1))-1
    ord2 <- 2*(1:length(v2))
    c(v1,v2)[order(c(ord1,ord2))]
  }

  insert_str <- function(target, insert, index) {
    insert <- insert[order(index)]
    index <- sort(index)
    paste(interleave(split_str_by_index(target, index), insert), collapse="")
  }

  # insert_str("1+1+5+8", c("(", ")"), c(2, 3))

  #################

  library(gtools)
  library(dplyr)

  symbols <- expand.grid(data.frame(matrix(rep(c("+","-","*","/"),3),ncol=3)))

  numbers <- unique(permutations(4,4,c(1,1,5,8),set=FALSE))

  # Insert symbols between the numbers
  lst <- lapply(1:nrow(numbers) , function(i) mapply(paste0,numbers[i,],symbols))
  res1 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst))

  # paste strings omitting the trailing symbol
  res2 <- res1 %>%
    transmute(expr=do.call(paste0,.)) %>%
    transmute(expr=substr(expr,1,7))

  # positions of opening and closing bracket
  x<-expand.grid(c(1,3,5),c(4,6,8))
  x<-x[x[1]<x[2]-1,]

  # Generate x rows for each row of res2
  res3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,nrow(res2)*nrow(x)),ncol=1))
  for (i in seq(nrow(res2))){
    temp <- res2[i,]
    res3[((i-1)*nrow(x)+1):(i*nrow(x)),] <- sapply(1:6, function(j) insert_str(temp,c("(", ")"),x[j,]))
  }

  res3  %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(result=eval(parse(text=V1))) %>%
    filter(result==10)
```

Comment: 8 + 1 + 1 + (5*0). It doesn't say you can't use other numbers :)

Comment: @RichardScriven `10+{c(1,1,5,8); 0}`, obviously.

Comment: Since you have working code and are asking for how to improve it, I would think that codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better spot to ask. Please be sure to check http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic before you post to make sure you follow all their posting guidelines.