# r: convert a string to date

Tags: r, as.date

I have a string like that:

```
201601 
201603 
201604 
201606 
201501
```

And I'd like to convert to Date, like so:

```
2016-01
2016-03
2016-04
2016-06
2015-01
```

I have tried:`df$month_key=as.Date(df$month_key,format="YYYYmm")`
But it asks for the origin, which we don't need to care about.
Is there a way to do that, or maybe add a dash between character 4 and 5 in the whole column?
Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863599/insert-a-character-at-a-specific-location-in-a-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `sub` to create a `-` between the first 4 characters and the next 2.  Match the four characters (`.{4}`), place it in a capture groups (`(...)`), followed by the next 2 characters in another capture group, replace it with the backreference for those groups (`\\1`, `\\2`) and in between we add the `-`.

```
df1$Col <- sub('(.{4})(.{2})', "\\1-\\2", df1$month_key)
df1$Col
#[1] "2016-01" "2016-03" "2016-04" "2016-06" "2015-01"
```

---

Another option is `substr/paste`

```
with(df1, paste(substr(month_key, 1,4), substr(month_key, 5, 6), sep="-"))
```

However, a `Date` class have a day as well.  So, to convert the original column to 'Date', we can append with any day, perhaps with `01` and use the format in `as.Date`

```
as.Date(paste0(df1$month_key, "01"), "%Y%m%d")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col = c(201601L, 201603L, 201604L, 201606L, 201501L
 )), .Names = "month_key", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: You don't have to convert the string to a date by inserting a hyphen. You can also consider using `zoo`: `library(zoo); as.yearmon("201603", "%Y%m")` (unfortunately, `lubridate` doesn't appear to do this yet). Answers from a different duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-yyyy-mm-format-to-a-date