# Searchbox in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, search-box

It is possible to add a general search box for the user to find a string in an output widget in Shiny? In the example below, I would like the user to type a string in the `textInput` widget and have Shiny highlight the matching text in the `verbatimTextOutput` (or something similar):

```
library(shiny)

text <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec quam ut tortor interdum pulvinar id vitae magna. Curabitur commodo consequat arcu et lacinia. Proin at diam vitae lectus dignissim auctor nec dictum lectus. Fusce venenatis eros congue velit feugiat, ac aliquam ipsum gravida. Cras bibendum malesuada est in tempus. Suspendisse tincidunt, nisi non finibus consequat, ex nisl condimentum orci, et dignissim neque est vitae nulla." 

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("search", "", placeholder = "Search term") 
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput("text")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$text <- renderText(paste(text))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So far, I have been working around this problem by splitting the text in fixed-length rows and using `grep` to display the location of the string in the text. (For example, alerting the user that the string `lorem` is in the first line).

Can it somehow be done more intuitively?

**Edit**

@Aurèle's answer is spot on. [`DT::dataTableOutput`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html) also provides a searchbox feature for finding strings in data.tables, without the higlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my naive attempt (does it satisfy the requirement of it being more intuitive?):

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

text <- paste(
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
  "consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec quam ut tortor", 
  "interdum pulvinar id vitae magna.", 
  "Curabitur commodo consequat arcu et lacinia.", 
  "Proin at diam vitae lectus dignissim auctor nec dictum lectus.", 
  "Fusce venenatis eros congue velit feugiat,", 
  "ac aliquam ipsum gravida. Cras bibendum malesuada est in tempus.", 
  "Suspendisse tincidunt, nisi non finibus consequat, ex nisl", 
  "condimentum orci, et dignissim neque est vitae nulla."
)
insert_mark_tag <- function(s, loc_index, all_locs) {
  str_sub(s, all_locs[loc_index, 2] + 1, all_locs[loc_index, 2]) <- "</mark>"
  str_sub(s, all_locs[loc_index, 1], all_locs[loc_index, 1] - 1) <- "<mark>"
  s
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("search", "", placeholder = "Search term") 
  ),
  htmlOutput("text")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    m <- if (nchar(input$search)) 
      str_locate_all(text, fixed(input$search))[[1]] else 
        matrix(ncol = 2)[FALSE, ]
    HTML(reduce_right(seq_len(nrow(m)), insert_mark_tag, all_locs = m, .init = text))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The keys are `str_locate_all()` and `str_sub<-`.

(you might want to use `coll()` instead of `fixed()`, and maybe replace `stringr` with `stringi`, I have no idea if the performance impact would be measurable).

I used @bartektartanus' (co-author of `stringi`) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45738272/6197649), btw I asked in a comment whether there is a cleaner way than this naive `reduce()`.

**Edit**

Actually, I have no idea why I made it so complicated. This is (much) simpler (though it behaves a little differently wrt regexes):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("search", "", placeholder = "Search term") 
  ),
  htmlOutput("text")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText(HTML(
    if (nchar(input$search))
      str_replace_all(text, sprintf("(%s)", input$search), "<mark>\\1</mark>") else
        text
  ))
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's an elegant solution. I'm wondering how does it work reactive?

Comment: Does exactly what I asked. However, I just realised that `DT::dataTableOutput` automatically provides a searchbox feature.

Comment: @amrrs : not sure what you're asking. `renderText()` watches `input$search` (which is a reactive value) and re-executes when it changes. At a lower level, I don't know, it's all Shiny-magic to me...

Comment: is your`str_replace_all` meant to insert those HTML tags at various locations on your string? I don't think I understand how it works and it's not working in my own case.

Comment: @FonsMA Yes, that is the idea. The `sprintf` part generates a simple regex pattern with a capturing group, which is referred to as `\1` in the replacement argument. Though it will not work with special characters that might break the regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks Aurèle, appreciate it! I think I get it now. Your `input$search` is actually a substring that is expected to already exist in `text` rather than a index value, which is what I need. I was confused because I reached this post from another question where you made a comment, where the issue was inserting at a certain length with `nchar()` and what not