# Modifying Strings to transform 1 into 01

Tags: r

I have an object that is a gigantic matrix with a vector, that contains a three letter string followed by a number like:

```
"aaa1" , "aaa2" , "aaa3" , "bbb1" ...
```

I would like to re-write this column so that the values 1-9 contain a 01-09 like:

```
"aaa01" , "aaa02" , "aaa03" , "bbb01" ...
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently?

One solution I came up with was to split the string from the number using

```
a <- substr(object$column , 1 , 3)
```

and then pasting the string with `sprintf` like

```
paste(a ,rep(sprintf("%02d",1:50))
```

Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Edit: the numbers in my sample can go over 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a character at a specific location in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863599/insert-a-character-at-a-specific-location-in-a-string)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The solution works if the numbers go only up to 9. I checked again, my sample has values that also go over 10. They take values like 25

Comment: Does not look good but...`paste0(gsub('\\d+', '', v1), sprintf('%02d', as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', v1))))`

Comment: This solution seems to work for my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sub` to add a 0 after the 3rd character like this:

```
data <- c("aaa1" , "aaa2" , "aaa3" , "bbb1")
sub('^(.{3})(.*)$', '\\10\\2', data)
```

Result:

```
[1] "aaa01" "aaa02" "aaa03" "bbb01"
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to add a 0 after the 3rd character but only for the names with 1 digit after their name, change the `*` for a `?` to specify that you are taking the expression when occurrence is 1:

```
v <- c("aaa1" , "aaa2" , "aaa3" , "bbb13", "aaa43")
sub('^(.{3})(.?)$', '\\10\\2', v)
```

Result:

```
[1] "aaa01" "aaa02" "aaa03" "bbb13" "aaa43"
```

As pointed out by @manotheshark you can be more strict with the rules of string pattern matching, by specifying that the 3rd character must be a word character with `w{3}`, and that the place to insert the 0 must be a one digit number with `\\d`:

```
sub('^(\\w{3})(\\d)$', '\\10\\2', v)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The solution works but only if the numbers following the string can take values between 1 and 9. I checked again, and my sample can have numbers higher than 9 i.e. it's possible to have "aaa35"

Comment: To ensure the results are expected it's better to be explicit instead of using wildcards:  `sub('^(\\w{3})(\\d)$', '\\10\\2', v)`

Comment: Thanks, I added your suggestion to the answer

Answer (score 1):

One way is with sub

```
Orig  = c("aaa1" , "aaa2" , "aaa3" , "bbb1")
sub("([a-z])(\\d)\\b", "\\10\\2", Orig)
```

[1] "aaa01" "aaa02" "aaa03" "bbb01"

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution

```
s <- c("aaa1" , "aaa2" , "aaa3" , "bbb1")
gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)","\\10",s)
```