# R - Efficiently insert multiple strings

Tags: r, string

I would like to insert a list of sub strings (`word_list`)  into a string (`text`) at specific positions (`idx_list`)

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
idx_list = c(5,16,30,50)
word_list = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
```

I know there are multiple possibilites functions (gsub, stri_sub etc.) which I can use in a loop. This gets however quite slow on large corpora. Is there a more efficient solution? Maybe vectorized?

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863599/insert-a-character-at-a-specific-location-in-a-string. Zach Foster's answer can be vectorized for this use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution 1

A small wrapper around `stringi` package function for input the OP wanted.

```
inject <- function(string, index, replacement){
  stringi::stri_sub_replace_all(string, from = index,
                                to = index-1,
                                replacement = replacement)
}

text <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
idx_list <- c(5, 16, 30, 50)
word_list <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")

inject(text, idx_list, word_list)
#> [1] "LoreAAAm ipsum dolBBBor sit amet, cCCConsectetur adipiscinDDDg elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

#### Solution 2

An adaptation of [Zach Foster's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863599/insert-a-character-at-a-specific-location-in-a-string) answer, condensed into a single function

```
inject_two <- function(string, inject, index) {
  inject <- inject[order(index)]
  index <- sort(index)
  # expand string
  split <- substr(rep(string, length(index) + 1),
    start = c(1, index),
    stop = c(index - 1, nchar(string))
  )
  ord1 <- 2 * (1:length(split)) - 1
  ord2 <- 2 * (1:length(inject))
  paste(c(split, inject)[order(c(ord1, ord2))], collapse = "")
}

inject_two(text, word_list, idx_list)
#> [1] "LoreAAAm ipsum dolBBBor sit amet, cCCConsectetur adipiscinDDDg elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

### Benchmarks

```
evans <- function(string, index, replacement){
  ord <- order(-index)
  Reduce(function(S, R) {
    paste0(substring(S, 1, R[[1]]-1), R[[2]], substring(S, R[[1]], nchar(S)))
  }, Map(list, index[ord], replacement[ord]), string)
}
ggplot2::autoplot(microbecnhmark::microbenchmark(
  inject(text, idx_list, word_list),
  inject_two(text, idx_list, word_list),
  evans(text, idx_list, word_list),
  times = 1000
))
```

[image: small set]

For few insertions all solutions perform similarly. What if we perform many (here N = 410 000) insertions?

```
text_large = paste0(rep(text, 10000), collapse = "")
idx_list_large = seq(1, nchar(text_large), by = 3)
word_list_large = sample(LETTERS, size = length(idx_list_large), replace = T)

bench::mark(
  inject = inject(text_large, idx_list_large, word_list_large),
  inject_two = inject_two(text_large, idx_list_large, word_list_large),
 iterations = 50
)[,c(1,3,5,7)]

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  expression   median mem_alloc n_itr
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:byt> <int>
1 inject       32.2ms    9.38MB    50
2 inject_two  157.4ms   65.69MB    50
```

Surprise surprise, C++ - based `stringi` takes the cake in both **speed and memory**. Note `evans` is omitted because 1 pass took multiple *minutes* when tested.

Comment: I think I prefer your single-pass (single-`paste`) implementation over my `Reduce` method.

Comment: @r2evans turns out its not the most efficient. Please check if I didn't do your implementation a disservice in the benchmark

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to start from the last (highest `idx_list`) first, since otherwise all numbers will need to be shifted. (This is certainly not hard, but going backwards seems easier.)

```r
#      0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         a         b         c
#      0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
idx_list = c(5,16,30,50)
word_list = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
```

The work:

```r
ord <- order(-idx_list)
Reduce(function(S, R) {
  paste0(substring(S, 1, R[[1]]-1), R[[2]], substring(S, R[[1]], nchar(S)))
}, Map(list, idx_list[ord], word_list[ord]), text)
# [1] "LoreAAAm ipsum dolBBBor sit amet, cCCConsectetur adipiscinDDDg elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

Walk-through:

- `ord` is just the decreasing order, so for instance

  ```r
  word_list[ord]
  # [1] "DDD" "CCC" "BBB" "AAA"
  ```
- because we're going to use `Reduce` (explanation in a second), we need the combination of `idx_list[1]` and `word_list[1]` to be in one argument, not individual; for this, we combine them using `Map(list, ...)`, which "zips" them together into a single list, each containing the character position and the string to insert:

  ```r
  str( Map(list, idx_list[ord], word_list[ord]) )
  # List of 4
  #  $ :List of 2
  #   ..$ : num 50
  #   ..$ : chr "DDD"
  #  $ :List of 2
  #   ..$ : num 30
  #   ..$ : chr "CCC"
  #  $ :List of 2
  #   ..$ : num 16
  #   ..$ : chr "BBB"
  #  $ :List of 2
  #   ..$ : num 5
  #   ..$ : chr "AAA"
  ```

  (This can be used with an arbitrary number of arguments.)
- Because we need to insert a string, then insert another string *into the result of the first*, the base function `Reduce` will work well here. The first arg is a function that accepts two arguments: the results from the previous call, and the next element from the `Map`'d argument.