# R Regular Expressions

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to insert a `-` in between the 2 and OT in `3-2OT` using R regular expressions. The end result should be `3-2-OT`. I have attempted \d+\d+, but was not correct.

Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: We're willing to help, but can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: There are dozens of potential solutions to your problem; what have you tried? Is this a single use-case, or do you need to add "-" to lots of strings? Do any of these solutions solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/13863599/12957340

Comment: @BenBolker I was missing parenthesis around the \\d-\\d. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried on your own? Anyway, here is one solution:

```
gsub("(3-2)(OT)", "\\1-\\2", "3-2OT")
# [1] "3-2-OT"
```

Comment: I'd encourage you to hold off on answering until OP revises their question - answering low-effort questions encourages them ...  (Although to be fair this answer is sufficiently specific that it won't actually help them much, unless this is a homework question, which seems unlikely ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Alright, I'll keep that in mind next time. But as you also point out I'm not sure of how much use this solution will be.

Comment: I almost had it. I was just missing the parenthesis around the digits. So I had \\d-\\d(OT). Thanks!