What is the most elegent way to insert characters (passed on as a vector) at a certain position in the string (passed on as vector) using stringr?
I need to insert the following characters: c("me3", "ac") in positions c(1, 6) in the following string KSTGGKAPR. What is the most elegant way to do this? Can I avoid writing a loop?

does elegant also mean as little code as possible?

Related post https://stackoverflow.com/q/13863599/680068

Please show expected output. What do you want to to with the characters already present at the listed positions?

Not so elegant but should work.
insert2string <- function(string, pieces, pos) {
  Map(
    \(i, j, piece) paste0(substr(string, i, j), piece), 
    c(0, pos), 
    c(pos, nchar(string)), 
    c(pieces, "")
  ) |>
    paste(collapse = "")
}

insert2string("KSTGGKAPR", c("me3", "ac"), c(1, 6))
# [1] "Kme3KSTGGKacKAPR"


insert2string("Pavel Shliaha", c("X", "Y", "Z"), c(0, 6, 14))
# [1] "XPavel Y ShliahaZ"


No loops, convert to raw, insert, convert it back to char:
x <- "KSTGGKAPR"
xRaw <- charToRaw(x)

rawToChar(c(charToRaw("me3"), 
            xRaw[ 1:5 ], 
            charToRaw("ac"),
            xRaw[ 6:length(xRaw)]))
# [1] "me3KSTGGacKAPR"


1) "Insert at" could either mean before or after the indicated positions. We show both. No packages are used.
x <- "KSTGGKAPR" # input

# 1a. before positions 1,6
sub("^(.....)(.*)", "me3\\1ac\\2", x)
## [1] "me3KSTGGacKAPR"

# 1b. after positions 1,6
sub("^(.)(.....)(.*)", "\\1me3\\2ac\\3", x)
## [1] "Kme3STGGKacAPR"

or maybe it means overwriting positions 1,2 and 6,7
# 1c
y <- x
substr(y, 1, 2) <- "me"
substr(y, 6, 7) <- "ac"
y
## [1] "meTGGacPR"

2) If the objective is to put "me" after the first K and "ac" after the second K then we can do this (and similarly if it is before).
# 2a.
sub("K(.*K)", "Kme\\1ac", x)
## [1] "KmeSTGGKacAPR"

If there can be any number of K's then try gsubfn.  This passes the match to the fun proto method replacing it with the output of the function.  gsubfn will insert the count into the proto object so that the fun method knows which match is referenced.
library(gsubfn)
p <- proto(v = c("me", "ac"), fun = function(this, x) v[count])

# 2b.
gsubfn("(?<=K)", p, x, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "KmeSTGGKacAPR"

# 2c.
gsubfn("(?=K)", p, x, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "meKSTGGacKAPR"

3) Read the string using read.fwf and use paste0 to put the parts back together with the new strings.  Similarly if before.
x |>
  textConnection() |>
  read.fwf(c(1, 5, 99)) |>
  with(paste0(V1, "me", V2, "ac", V3))
## [1] "KmeSTGGKacAPR"

Update
Add 1c and 2.
Fix 2.
Add 3.

With stringi
library(stringi)

st <- "KSTGGKAPR"

stri_sub_replace_all(st, c(1,6), c(0,0), replacement=c("me3", "ac"))
[1] "me3KSTGGacKAPR"

